# Python: How to search for multiple items in a list

Tags: python

So i have a list with number values such as 
my_num = [1,2,2,3,4,5]

What i want is a code that will check if 1, 2 and 3 are in the list.
What i had in mind was:

if 1 and 2 and 3 in my_num:

do something

but the problem is if 1 and 3 are in the list the do something code executes anyways even without the 2 being there.

Comment: Please show your work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4]
>>> if (1 in nums) and (2 in nums) and (3 in nums):
...   print('ok')
...
ok
>>> if (1 in nums) and (2 in nums) and (9 in nums):
...   print('ok')
...
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. I understand a bit why yours worked compared to mine. Yours will check each one individually

Comment: Sure thing @CYLegends! Feel free to click the check mark if this helped you see how to implement multiple conditionals simultaneously in Python :)

Answer (score 6):

Check out the standard library functions `any` and `all`.  You can write this:

```
if any(a in my_num for a in (1, 2, 3)):
    # do something if one of the numbers is in the list
if all(a in my_num for a in (1, 2, 3)):
    # do something if all of them are in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if 1 and 2 and 3 in my_num:
```

is not doing what you think it does: it tests `if 1` which is `True`, and `if 2`, which is also `True`, then `if 3 in my_num`

You must test for each condition individually:

```
if 1 and in my_num and 2 in my_num and 3 in my_num:
```

Answer (score 0):

If lists lenghs are long:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
_in = [2, 3, 4]
if len(set(_in)) == len(set(nums)&set(_in)):
    print("ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

Depend on [Paul Cornelius](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46985660/6049334) answer, I add something and some improvements to make it more understandable

```
number_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
search_nums = [1, 2]
if any(num in number_list for num in search_nums):
     # Is any number in search_nums inside of number_list do something
if all(num in number_list for num in search_nums):
     # Is all numbers in search_nums inside of number_list do something
```

Searching list in list of lists

```
list_number_list = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]]
search_nums = [1, 2]
for number_list in list_number_list:
     if any(num in number_list for num in search_nums):
          # Is any number in search_nums inside of number_list do something
     if all(num in number_list for num in search_nums):
          # Is all numbers in search_nums inside of number_list do something
```